# Elasticsearch's NEST API does not return query results while the same query is successful when submitting by POSTMAN

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

The following code snippet is a MoreLikeThis query built using NEST API:

```
private class Temp
{
     public string Content { get; set; }
     public string TextToSearch { get; set; }
}

var temp = new Temp
{
   TextToSearch = "empire",
};

var response = await model.ElasticClient.SearchAsync<Temp>(s => s
                .Query(q => q
                    .MoreLikeThis(qd => qd
                        .Like(l => l.Text(temp.TextToSearch))
                        .MinTermFrequency(1)
                        .MinDocumentFrequency(1)
                        .Fields(fd => fd.Fields(r => r.Content)))));
```

After executing this code snippet `response.Documents` did not return any records. But when the following JSON payload is **POST**ed by POSTMAN, the results are received successfully:

```
{"query":{"more_like_this":{"fields":["content"],"like":["advanced technology"],"min_doc_freq":1,"min_term_freq":1}}}
```

This payload is generated by the C# code snippet above when enabling audit trail. While the credentials are passed in both cases properly why the NEST API version 6.5.0 does not receive documents from the elastic search instance?

Is there a bug in the library or we're missing a point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides the `TextToSearch` being `"empire"` in the C# example and `"advanced technology"` in the JSON query DSL example, I strongly suspect that the issue here is that of the index and type being targeted in the NEST case.

When no index and type are provided in the API call:

For index,

1. Will look to see if there is a default index to use for `Temp` type configured with  `DefaultMappingFor<T>` on `ConnectionSettings`
2. If no default index for `Temp`, will use the `DefaultIndex` configured on `ConnectionSettings`
3. If no default index is configured on `ConnectionSettings`, the API call will not be made and NEST will throw an exception to indicate that it does not have enough information to make the API call.

For type,

1. Will look to see if there is a default type name to use for `Temp` type configured with  `DefaultMappingFor<T>` on `ConnectionSettings`
2. Will look to see if a type name convention is configured using `DefaultTypeNameInferrer` on `ConnectionSettings`. If none is configured, or the delegate it is configured with returns `null` or `""` for a given type, then will continue
3. Will look to see if a default type name is specified with `DefaultTypeName` on `ConnectionSettings`. If none is specified, a type name will be inferred for a POCO type by lowercasing the type name. For `Temp`, this will be `temp`.

So, assuming you have a default index configured and no convention for type names, the request URI for your NEST example will be

```
<configured uri>/<default index>/temp/_search
```

which probably does not match what you are using in Postman.

Check out the documentation to see more details about [Index name inference](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/index-name-inference.html) and [Type name inference](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/types-and-relations-inference.html).

Comment: Yes, the C# example should have been "advanced technology" too. That was a typo. Thanks for the answer and I will get back to you after examining your steps.

Comment: The issue was the type name was not lowercase. Thanks @russ